# How styling works over components in angular?

Tags: css, angular

Question is not clear but I'll break it down. In angular we can write isolated css for styling. It works pretty well for native html elements. But unlike react, angular wrap our html with custom elements like `<app-card>...</app-card>`. When I write css for those wrapper elements, it doesn't work .

If I have a post list like

```
<div class="post-list">
   <app-card [post]="post" *ngFor="let post of posts"></app-card>
</div>
```

If I write css to apply some vertical gap between `app-card` components in `PostListComponent`. Well nothing happens.

```css
.post-list app-card:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

How can I make it work? Or with angular logic, how can I apply vertical gap between angular components

Comment: Just add **display: block;** on your **app-card** component & it will work as expected. See working example in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` on your `app-card` component & it will work as expected.

```css
.post-list app-card {
    display: block;
}


.post-list app-card:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-list">
   <app-card>Card 1</app-card>
   <app-card>Card 2</app-card>
   <app-card>Card 3</app-card>
</div>
```

Comment: well, it actually worked. I didn't expect that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TeomanTıngır Actually by default angular components are inline elements, so you were applying margin on inline element & margin only works with block elements that's why your style was not working.

Comment: I see. I was leak of that knowledge, thou, I didn't think about the display property of a component.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the iteration in `div` tag then add your class

```
<div class="post-list">
   <div class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
       <app-card [post]="post"></app-card>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in your css

```
.post-list .post:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: I know there are some workarounds. I'm looking something more efficent, creating extra elements or changing encapsulation mode instead

Answer (score 0):

You can define `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your Component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: './foo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class FooComponent { }
```

Which will treat your .css as the same if you were putting it in the global scope.

To be more accurate, it won't **append** .fooComponent to **each css rule in foo.component.scss**.

Comment: I know there are some workarounds. I'm looking something more efficent, creating extra elements or changing encapsulation mode instead

Comment: This example changes the  encapsulation mode

Comment: I know, I appreciate your help but I'm looking more elegant way to achieve it. Instead of violating the moduler styling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason it shouldn't work. Just tried to put in some of your code here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-icqrye

app.component.html

```
<div class="post-list">
  <app-new *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]"></app-new>
</div>
```

styles.scss

```
.post-list app-new:not(:last-child) p {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  color: green;
}
```

And it works perfectly. Are you looking for something else?

And if you want to add the style (margins) to the component directly, you will first need to set the display of the component to block/flex as per requirement.

```
.post-list app-new:not(:last-child) {
  display: flex;
}
```

[image]